# const char * comparation with ==

Tags: c, arrays, char, constants, design-patterns

I have a function that returns a const char * to a fixed value and when i am using this function i do a "==" operator to find eguality between the value returned and the one i expect. Is this a good practice? Should it be an anti-pattern?
Ex:

```
const char * LOL = "LOL";  

const char * getI() {  
    return LOL;  
}

main {  
    if (getI() == LOL)  
        something();  
}
```

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440420/compare-equality-of-char-in-c

Comment: That possible dublicate is about how you should compare string content. This question might not be about that.

Comment: Everytime I see `LOL` I end up laughing. I must be a nerd.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is this a good practice?

Well, that depends.

It's the right thing to do if and only if you want to test whether the pointer returned by `getl()` points to the same string literal as the global `LOL` pointer.  If that's not what you want to do, then, no, it's not good practice.

Answer (score 3):

That depends.  If you are trying to detect that the instances of the strings are the same, it's the correct thing to do.  If you are trying to detect whether the contents of the strings are the same, then it isn't.

Comment: The contents are the same cause they are the same global const variable. Agree?

Comment: In this particular case, yes they're the same. What needs to be considered  is whether you also want `if(getl() == "FOO")` to compare as true, or if you want `if(getl() == getx())` to return true, if getx() also returns an arbitary pointer to a "LOL" string.

Answer (score 2):

As others have said, it depends what you want to do.

When you say "the value I expect", what do you mean? What *do* you expect?

Withouot knowing your answer to that: In general, bad practice. As far as I know, compilers can cleverly reuse the location of strings. So this behavior:

```
const char *LOL = "lol";
const char *test = "lol";
return (test == LOL);
```

is not well-defined.

Answer (score 1):

Well,... you're trying to return a value with a global name, so that the code is more readable, right? (if I misinterpreted, ignore :P). The reasoning is great, but that's not the way to go.

The usual way of doing this is `#define`:

```
#define MY_MEANINGFUL_RETURN 1

int doSomething() {
    return MY_MEANINGFUL_RETURN;
}

(...)
    if (doSomething() == MY_MEANINGFUL_RETURN)
(...)
```

If you used the const char* techique above, you'd have to store those strings in memory during execution, to then compare only their memory position. With this second approach, the compiler manages the numbers and you get pretty names without demanding any additional time or space.

Comment: I have to work with char *, so i choose to do "const char *"  in advance of #define "string" cause it would create an automatic variable every place i reference it and const char * saves space for me.

Comment: If you have to work with char*, I answered the wrong question :)

Answer (score 1):

Object identity versus equality:

If you are going to use it as a way/construct to "identify" the objects (in this case the global pointer LOL which is effectively just the SAME object in your line of code), then it is safe.

But taking a deeper look at your example, it seems like what you really wanna do is check for "equality" : i.e. test if the two objects are equal i.e. do they contain same value?