# Program is telling me arguments don't match even when they clearly do

Tags: c++

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngBFl.jpg)
so my C++ program connects to my server to download and install the latest version. When an update is available, it will download the Setup.exe file then launch it. The setup.exe installs the new files then launches the new program with the '-rs' argument. The update code both client/server side works perfectly but for some reason the program is not picking up the '-rs' argument. It is telling me '-rs' is not specified which is very strange because if I type std::cout << argv[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngBFl.jpg) it will print -rs to the console. I even tried making a shortcut that launches the program with '-rs' and it still says -rs is not equal to -rs.

```
if (argc == 2)
    {
        std::cout << "There are 2 arguments." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'" << argv[1] << "' is the second argument." << std::endl;
        if (argv[1] != "-rs")
        {
            std::cout << "'" << argv[1] << "' is not equal to '-rs' WTF?" << std::endl;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare equality of char\[\] in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2440420/compare-equality-of-char-in-c)

Comment: That's not how you compare C-style strings.

Answer (score 0):

*You are comparing a single character pointer to the whole array of characters try giving argv != "-rs" your conditional statement is wrong. And yes if you are taking command line arguments then you need to give 2 indexes for which you want to compare for e.g. argv[index][index]*

```
        std::cout << "There are 2 arguments." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'" << argv[1] << "' is the second argument." << std::endl;
        if (argv != "-rs")
        {
            std::cout << "'" << argv[1] << "' is not equal to '-rs' WTF?" << std::endl;
        }
```

***OR***

```
        char argv[2][4] = {"-ws","-rs"};
        std::cout << "There are 2 arguments." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "'" << argv[1] << "' is the second argument." << std::endl;
        if (argv[1] != "-rs")
        {
            std::cout << "'" << argv[1] << "' is not equal to '-rs' WTF?" << std::endl;
        }
```